# what would be an appropriate SE site to ask sysadmin questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I am in need of some direction in researching PBX systems. I've got a basic Systems Administration question regarding PBX's, but I'm not sure which SE site would be most appropriate for that... Would it be Server Fault, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a shopping or product comparison question, it's not going to be on-topic anywhere.  Otherwise, ServerFault is probably your best bet.  Read [QA is hard, let's go shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and [Gorilla vs Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) first.

Comment: Yup, I realize that I can't ask "shopping" questions. I'm more so thinking it's researched based, similar to this gaming question I asked - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/if-i-like-game-x-how-do-i-find-similar-games

Comment: alright, here's what I put up. http://serverfault.com/questions/394012/when-researching-an-ip-phone-system-where-would-you-start

Comment: OK.  We'll see how it flies.